# c++ socket accept, list of connected clients

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

I have a few question about socket in c++!

First question, let's say that he writes a server for the game in which he will play 200 people at once, but accept is blocked because he already serves one client, how to deal with it?

Second question, how to download a list of all currently connected clients, so that you can then send a message to everyone?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Goggle search for this, it's been answered in may game development forums. Or try https://www.gamedev.net/forums/forum/8-networking-and-multiplayer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a few question about socket in c++!

For future reference, please post only one question at a time. If you have multiple questions, post them separately.

> let's say that he writes a server for the game in which he will play 200 people at once, but accept is blocked because he already serves one client, how to deal with it?

Use sockets in non-blocking mode, using `select()`/`(e)poll()` or other callback mechanisms to know which sockets have pending activity and when.

Otherwise, use `accept()` in a separate thread than other thread(s) used to service connected clients.

> how to download a list of all currently connected clients, so that you can then send a message to everyone?

The server is responsible for keeping track of its connected clients. Then it can loop through that list when needed.

If a client wants to send a message to every other client, the best option is for it to send a single message to the server and ask the server to relay the message to every other client.

Otherwise, the client would have to request the list from the server, and then send a message to every other client individually.